Error converting tif file to mbtiles file using rio-mbtiles in AWS Lambda
I have a fairly basic Python and shell script that Lambda runs inside a Docker container whenever an upload of a .tif file occurs within an S3 bucket. The general flow is that the Python downloads the uploaded .tif file into /tmp and then runs the shell script to apply a color scale to the raster, reproject the raster to EPSG:4326 (just in case), convert the .tif to .mbtiles, and then .mbtiles to .pmtiles. Here is the code for the Python and shell script:
def handler(event, context):
    new_object_info = event['Records'][0]['s3']
    bucket_name = new_object_info['bucket']['name']
    file_path = new_object_info['object']['key']

    print(f"New object has been uploaded to bucket {bucket_name}: {file_path}")

    local_tif_path = os.path.join('/tmp', os.path.basename(file_path))

    try:
        s3_client.download_file(bucket_name, file_path, local_tif_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting file {file_path} from bucket {bucket_name}. Error: {e}")
        raise e
    
    current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    script_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "pmtiles_from_tiffs.sh")
    command = [script_path, local_tif_path]

    # Run the command
    result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    print(f"{result.returncode}, {result.stdout}, {result.stderr}")

    # Check if the command was successful
    if result.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception()
    
    return "Final return."

#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <local_tiff_dir>"
    exit 1
fi

LOCAL_TIF_PATH=$1

base_name=$(basename $LOCAL_TIF_PATH .tif)

temp_tiff="/tmp/${base_name}_rgba.tif"
gdaldem color-relief $LOCAL_TIF_PATH color_relief.txt $temp_tiff -alpha

reprojected_tiff="/tmp/${base_name}_rgba_4326.tif"
echo "Reprojecting to: $reprojected_tiff"
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 $temp_tiff $reprojected_tiff

if [ ! -f "$reprojected_tiff" ] || [ ! -s "$reprojected_tiff" ]; then
    echo "Error: $reprojected_tiff is empty or does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

mbtiles_file="/tmp/${base_name}.mbtiles"
echo "Creating MBTiles: $mbtiles_file"
ls -l /tmp
rio mbtiles $reprojected_tiff $mbtiles_file --zoom-levels 3..14 --rgba --format PNG

pmtiles_file="/tmp/${base_name}.pmtiles"
echo "Converting to PMTiles: $pmtiles_file"
/function/pmtiles convert $mbtiles_file $pmtiles_file

done

echo "Processing complete."

exit 0

This all works locally, including running each individual command with sample files, but once I upload the container build to ECR and test it by uploading a .tif to my S3 bucket, the shell script produces an error:
START RequestId: 02b7299d-0972-4c26-b02d-1c2c8c6cdca2 Version: $LATEST
New object has been uploaded to bucket geocarbondb: test_25_projects/1008.tif
1, 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Reprojecting to: /tmp/1008_rgba_4326.tif
Using band 4 of source image as alpha.
Creating output file that is 184P x 121L.
Processing /tmp/1008_rgba.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Creating MBTiles: /tmp/1008.mbtiles
total 220
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sbx_user1051 990 44942 Aug 27 16:09 1008.tif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sbx_user1051 990 89516 Aug 27 16:09 1008_rgba.tif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sbx_user1051 990 89516 Aug 27 16:09 1008_rgba_4326.tif
, Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/rio", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main_group())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mbtiles/scripts/cli.py", line 581, in mbtiles
process_tiles(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mbtiles/cf.py", line 33, in process_tiles
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 662, in __init__
self._call_queue = _SafeQueue(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 168, in __init__
super().__init__(max_size, ctx=ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 43, in __init__
self._rlock = ctx.Lock()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__
sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The error occurs at the rio mbtiles command. I've done some things like logging the files in /tmp and a check to see if the $reprojected_tiff file exists before rio mbtiles. I've also looked through the docs of this command (https://github.com/mapbox/rio-mbtiles) and searched to see if others were getting a similar error in similar situations but haven't really made any progress yet. I haven't seen anything obviously wrong, but I am very new to things like Docker and rasters and I don't have a lot of experience in Python so any help or information would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
No need for an answer to this anymore. I changed my approach by creating a new Python script that runs locally and processes the tifs before they are downloaded to the S3 bucket, removing the need for a Lambda function and Docker container.
